# Upgrading Android App with pre-built database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an Android App with a pre-built SQLite DB packaged with it. However, I'm sure that if I want to do an upgrade with an upgraded/altered/new database it will be tricky.
I found this out on my emulator and handset. When I changed DBs (keeping the name the same, or altered the DB and put it back into the assets directory, and then ran the app on the emulator, it wouldn't read the new DB, but would keep the old database. The only way to get rid of the old DB, it seems, is to delete the app and reinstall it. WHich is what I do when I test my apps on my handset after changing the database. Another option is to change the name of the database, and all references to it in the code, but this doubles the database storage of the app and wastes space.

Comment: Can't you just drop the old database, or the relevant tables, then import your new sql data?

Comment: How do I drop a database in an upgrade? Its already on the customers phone. If I add a new database to my package then the old database is just wasting space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at SQLiteOpenHelper - it will help you maintain the DB within your app.

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842

It also has a database version property which you can increment, and it wipes the DB and recreates it. It also allows you to update your database easily, without affecting user data (if you plan on doing future updates to your app).

I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks. After a cursory glance that does look like what I'm looking for. I just wonder whether I can retroactively put this code into the upgrade of an already released app.

Comment: Not sure how your app is designed, but you'd probably have to do a bit of re-writing to work it in. Definitely worth it though.